# Permanent opened DrawerLayout

Tags: android

Is there a way to make Android's new DrawerLayout permanently open?

I want it for the Tablet design, but I didn't find anything on Google's documentations.

Anyone knows anything?

Comment: If you want it permanently open, that defeats the purpose of the drawer.  Just have a linear layout with a fixed panel ("drawer") and a match_parent one for the rest of the layout

Comment: That will do I guess. Thank you

Comment: Maybe what you want is a master-detail layoout for tablets.

Comment: I thought of using the same layout for both. But I can still do it that way

Comment: Well if it is master-detail layout , then head down slidingpanelayout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation Drawer: set as always opened on tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133541/navigation-drawer-set-as-always-opened-on-tablets)

Answer (score 1):

this is method to disable swipe to open

drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments. That kind of defeats the purpose of the drawer layout. To answer the question though, there are 2 ways to open the DrawerLayout.

1. You have to call `drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navDrawerList);` or `drawerLayout.openDrawer(navDrawerList);` when the user presses something. As expected the respective call will close or open the navigation drawer.
2. The drawer can be opened via a Bezel swipe (A swipe from the very edge of the phone on the side of the nav drawer). I currently know of no way to disable the Bezel swipe.

Hope this helps.